# How to check IIS reset or not by Octopus

Tags: iis, octopus-deploy, octopus

We have a MVC application and we are using Jenkin and Octopus for the deployment. We have used the Octopus for the deployment. There is an step to restart the IIS through the octopus. We need to check if the IIS has been restarted by the Octoups or not after the deployment. Is there any log or technique by which I can check this.

Comment: you can check the event viewer, Like for other windows services, it also keeps track of service restarts on the System Log of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Poewrshell script` as a step in octopus and add/write some log statements using `Write-Host` before and after `Restart-WebAppPool` cmdlet.

Here is the sample code of the same you can add `try catch` also

```
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ff") : Restarting Default App pool"
Restart-WebAppPool -Name "Default"
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ff") : Default App pool restarted"
```

**Output is like :**

```
04-07-2019 10:14:28:15 : Restarting Default App pool
04-07-2019 10:14:28:16 : Default App pool restarted
```

Note : you have to use Octopus variable to set AppPool name on runtime ( dynamic )

Answer (score 0):

There are couple options, like capturing into the variable in `Octopus Deploy` the status of iis reset. Or getting the information on the last IIS start from the event logs.[image]

Below PS script should give you a possible solution for when getting it from the event logs:

```
$Events = Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source IISCTLS -Newest 1 -Message '*start command received*'
$DateTimeNow = Get-Date
if ($DateTimeNow.AddMinutes(-5) -lt  $Events.TimeGenerated){
    "happened less than 5 min ago"
}
else {
    "happened long ago"
}
```